# Доступ к полю связанной таблицы при связи «hasOne/hasMany» в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Хочу в `$this->title` вывести название категории из связанной таблицы.

```
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']);
}
```

Как можно обратиться, чтобы вместо `category_id` можно было подставить `category.name`, как например в виджете GridView: там в атрибутах просто можно прописать `category.name` и будет выводить то что нужно. Тут можно также?

```
$this->title = $model->category_id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример из [документации](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/db-active-record.md) ...

---

[Метод получения связанных данных](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/db-active-record.md#%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%B9-):

```
public function getOrders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::className(), ['customer_id' => 'id']);
}
```

[Доступ к связанным данным](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/db-active-record.md#%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-)

> После объявления связей вы можете получать доступ к связным данным с помощью имён связей. Это происходит таким же образом, каким осуществляется доступ к свойству объекта объявленному с помощью метода получения связных данных. По этой причине, мы называем его *свойством связи*. Например:

```
// SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `id` = 123
$customer = Customer::findOne(123);

// SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE `customer_id` = 123
// $orders - это массив объектов Order
$orders = $customer->orders;
```

> **Info:** когда вы объявляете связь с названием `xyz` посредством геттера `getXyz()`, у вас появляется возможность доступа к свойству `xyz` подобно свойству объекта. Помните, что название связи чувствительно к регистру.

---

**В вашем случае это будет выглядеть так:**

```
$model->category->name;
```